# Webform component email does not follow other form formatting

Tags: 7, theming, webforms

I implemented a webform with an email component which does not follow the regular formatting set up for forms.

- It does not put the label above the field (despite it being requested in the settings).
- The field is not in the same colour or length than the others.

[image]

Is there a clean way to correct this? I need to add that I am picking up from a colleague who left, so trying to figure this out by myself!

PS: I also have the same problem with a term reference field which uses autocomplete deluxe widget in a regular node form. I am guessing the solution will be similar.